# How do you create a Linq IQueryable Where query with string predicate and params object[] arguments

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to create a `IQueryable` `Where` method as shown below:

```
public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, string predicate, params object[] values)
{}
```

So instead of `Where(u => u.Points >= 20)` I could pass a string predicate like `Where("Points >= param0", 20)`

What would be involved in accomplishing this task?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: So a user can input a query or function ((10 * Cos(param0)) + parm1) >= 3, with params (4, 7). I would like a user in a WinForm to enter a predicate   with params and this would be executed with a result.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139467/how-to-create-linq-query-from-string) SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code to accomplish what you are asking is large, it is easier to use NuGet package [NequeoLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NequeoLinq/). Sample code,
first add the extension

```
using Nequeo.Extension;
using Nequeo.Linq.Extension;
```

On any collection type:

```
Where("ProOne >= @0 && ProTwo <= @1", 30, 70);
```

Pass the predicate as a string containing the property names of the collection type and the collection of parameters contained in the predicate (@0, @1 refer to 30 and 70).

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
```

it has

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> source,
      string predicate,
      params object[] args);
```

Comment: Good answers should provide additional content and more full explanations. Although this may work, why does it work? Does it have any limitations?